# How to set background image is gif image in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am try to set animated Gif image to the background image of the page but not luck. Can we set Gif image to the Xaml page background image? If yes please suggest any idea.

I have directly set gif image to the background, but it shows only first image of the gif.

Comment: Why does it have to be a *gif*? Can you set a *png* for example?

Comment: I have to show multiple images in background one after another. so what's my plan is create gif image with required images and set it to background. then it will show images one after another.

Comment: So you actually want an *animated* gif as background? Well, what happens if you set such a gif as background? I don't expect it works, but it's the first thing you should test (and tell us in the question).

Comment: I have directly set gif image to the background but it shows only first image of the gif. That's why I have posted the question for finding any other ways.

Comment: If it works like that, then most likely the framework just doesn't support animated backgrounds (I'd be slightly surprised if it did). So you need some kind of view (media player, web view, whatever) as the background, which can display them. Or if it's ok to have a series of independent images instead of single animated gif, you could change the background and do the animation yourself that way.

Comment: Is able to show text on palying video?

Comment: jpg and png are the only supported image formats

Comment: Might I add that this is the third time you're asking this question or a very minor variation of it on here in the span of 1 day? I would advise to keep all discussion to 1 question since they're so similar.